# TeraData Date function to SQL Server equivalent

Tags: sql-server, datetime, teradata

I need some help in understanding the following piece of code that I need to translate to SQL Server.

```
where
srch_req_dttm > ( Date -  '+CAST(@Intval AS VARCHAR(10))+ ') 
and srch_req_dttm < date
```

What does the "Date" part in above signify? Is it an equivalent of GETDATE() function in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE` in Teradata will get the current date. To do the same in Sql Server you will need to use `GETDATE()`... but `GETDATE()` also returns the time, so it's not an exact match for the `DATE` function in Teradata.

You can use `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` in SQL Server, however, to get just the date back. It's pretty verbose, but I believe it's the closest match.